# Unable to use array on reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

```
Const people = [ { name: 'siddiq', age: 20} , { name: 'anas', age: 19}]

Const arr = people.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.push(curr.age), [])
```

It is not working. What i want is to creare an array with only ages...??

Comment: It's `const`, not `Const`

Comment: Why are you using `reduce`? This is what `map` is for.

Comment: Also what **exactly** does "it is not working" mean? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported?

Comment: In the first iteration `push` returns the length of the array, which becomes the value of `acc` in the next iteration and then `push` is not a method of that number.

Comment: You need to return the accumulator (acc) on each iteration of reduce.

Comment: To expan on @Barmar's comment. Use `Array.map` whenever you want to create a new array that has results based on each element from a source array.

Answer (score 4):

You should use map() instead:

```
const people = [ { name: 'siddiq', age: 20} , { name: 'anas', age: 19}]

const arr = people.map(p => p.age)
//[20, 19]
```

Answer (score 3):

`reduce()` requires that you return the accumulator from the callback function (since the accumulator might not be a mutable object). `push()` returns the length of the updated array, so the second iteration tries to do `(1).push(curr.age, [])`, which doesn't work.

The comma operator is useful for this in arrow functions.

Also, there's no reason to push `[]` onto `acc`.

```js
const people = [ { name: 'siddiq', age: 20} , { name: 'anas', age: 19}]
const arr = people.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc.push(curr.age), acc), []);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to ensure you'll return an array within `reduce` method in a cleaner and modern way.

```js
const people = [ { name: 'siddiq', age: 20} , { name: 'anas', age: 19}]
const arr = people.reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr.age], []);

console.log(arr);
```